# Why the following program giving exit failure?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Read the following program and tell me what would be the output.

```
f(int n)
  {
      static int i=1;
      if(n>=5) return n;
      n=n+i;
      i++;
  }

main()
{

  f(1);
}
```

The book [CS Computer Science and IT: Practice Book for PSUs](http://www.bookadda.com/books/cs-computer-science-practice-book-made-easy-9381069328-9789381069325) where I got the question says `7`, but while compiling I am getting "**exit failure**"

What may be the reason for this? Can any one explain me this!

---

Code from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20341148/why-the-following-program-giving-exit-failure?noredirect=1#comment30362305_20341166) to [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20341166/15168):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
static int i=1;
f(int n)
{
    if(n>=5)
        return n;
    n=n+i;
    printf("Before - %d\n",i);
    i++;
    printf("after - %d\n",i);
}

main()
{
    int y;
    y=f(1);
    printf("Main - %d\n",y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What book did you get this from and are you sure this is the complete program? `f` has undefined behavior when it falls off the end w/o a return.

Comment: What is the exact output of the compiler?

Comment: Unrelated: I'm hoping the useless action of `n=n+i;` in the presented code is obvious.

Comment: Are you compiling with a pre-standard compiler, a C89/C90 compiler, or a C99 or later compiler? And how many warnings are you getting from the C99 or later compiler if that's what you're using?  The code is written in sloppy C89 style, and the absence of an explicit return from `main()` means you get whatever random value the compiler happens to leave around as the exit status, and there's approximately a very good chance that the value is not 0, which indicates success. If the compiler is C99, it should give a number of diagnostics and, if it generates a program, it will exit with status 0.

Comment: So, is your compiler compiling your program successfully and reporting 'exit failure' when the program is run, or is it failing to compile the program at all?  There's no particular reason to think the exit status from the program will be 7 (it might be, but it would be an odd accident if it was).  The code is atrocious; the author should be dragged kicking and screaming into the latter part of the 1990s, and preferably into the current decade.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i don't know i have compiled on codepad and showing so

Comment: Ah! You're using codepad. Well that explains where the message is coming from. This would have been useful information right up front.

Comment: @WhozCraig there are bigger issues then that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `main()` function is not returning anything (which means its return value is undefined, and the return value of `main()` is reported as the exit code of the program). Change it to:

```
int main()
{
    f(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, if you expect your program to print anything at all, then you'll have to add statement(s) to do so.

Comment: Many compilers will make main return int implicitly even though that was taken out in C99.

Comment: you are upto mark it remove the exit failure while ans is still 10.

Comment: @RajeevKumar there is no output from the program how are you seeing a result of `10`?

Comment: This answer doesn't have enough caveats in place. It probably describes the OP's (unidentified) platform accurately, but the comments are not accurate if the compiler is running in C99 or C11 mode -- then the return status of `main()` is zero (but there are other problems in the code).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour i am using my own printf to display the return value by function f

Comment: @RajeevKumar: how can we possibly tell what your code is going to do if you don't show us the code you are compiling?

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
static int i=1;
 f(int n)
  {
      
      if(n>=5) return n;
      n=n+i;
printf("Before - %d\n",i);
      i++;
printf("after - %d\n",i);
  }

main()
{
   
 int y;
  
  y=f(1);
printf("Main - %d\n",y);
return 0;
}

Answer (score 2):

With C99, exit code will be `0`. With older C standards, exit code is unspecified.

> 5.1.2.2.3 Program termination
>
> ... reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

f() also does not have a return type, and not all code paths will return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Pre C99 both `main` and `f` will implicitly return `int`, even in C99 mode many compilers will still do this as an extension.  To fix your exit failure, adding:

```
return 0 ;
```

at the end of `main` should fix this, in C99 it should return `0` but before C99 the return value is *unspecified* and so could be anything.

The other major issue is that unless `n` is `5` you will fall off the end of `f` without a return which is undefined behavior in a value returning function if you use the return value. From the C99 draft standard section `6.9.1` *Function definitions* paragraph *12*:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by
>   the caller, the behavior is undefined.

so every path needs an explicit return in `f`. The result from your function is due to [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and so really anything can happen.

We can see this all confirmed by looking at the warning generated by `clang` in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfd9079e4a6f2bb3). The warnings we see are as follows:

```
main.cpp:4:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

f(int n)
^

main.cpp:12:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

}
^

main.cpp:14:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

main()
^~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

t sounds like your shared cache is being offloaded due to inactivity. One way to test this would be to add an In-Role Cache to an existing service (if available) and swap your cache usage to this new cache. In-Role cache is described here.

Once the cache is moved off of a shared offering, wait the requisite 1-2 minutes for idle time out and retry the connection, the delay should not be present.

Assuming you want to stick with the shared cache option after isolating the problem, the only current workaround that I am aware of is running a background task that will periodically ping the cache to keep it alive.

If you are running a full Web role you can launch a background task on application start up.
If you deploying via Mobile Services, then you can run the "ping" via Scheduled Jobs. The only issue you may run into here is that the minimum time for a scheduled job is 1 minute, which may not be aggressive enough to keep your cache alive 100% of the time.http://www.valuze.com/